# Set Color to JButton without adjusting border

Tags: java, swing

I want to create a red `JButton`:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class RedButtonTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame  frame   = new JFrame("Red Button Color Test");
                JPanel  pane1   = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
                JPanel  pane2   = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
                JButton button1 = new JButton();
                JButton button2 = new JButton();

                frame.setSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
                button1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
                button2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
                button2.setBackground(Color.red);
                button2.setBorderPainted(false); //This line
                button2.setOpaque(true);

                pane1.add(button1);
                pane2.add(button2);
                frame.add(pane1, BorderLayout.WEST);
                frame.add(pane2, BorderLayout.EAST);

                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Is there a way to make the button red without using

```
setBorderPainted(false);
```

When not using it, the borders turn red and not the button itself, however, I do not want to use this line because it removes the soft edges of the button. Is there another way to color a button?

Comment: Alternative solution: You can paint its border to a chosen Color like this:

button2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));

Comment: The answer has already been given in the other posting that this is a LAF issue. This information was not mentioned in this question. If you use a Mac and know a solution then check out the other posting. Keep all the information about the problem together in a single posting so everybody knows what has already been discussed and suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `button2.setContentAreaFilled(false);`. This will keep the edges but sets the background color. According to the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html):

> If true the button will paint the content area. If you wish to have a
> transparent button, such as an icon only button, for example, then you
> should set this to false. Do not call setOpaque(false). The default
> value for the the contentAreaFilled property is true.

Comment: Sorry, this does not work. If you try to insert this line in my above example, you see that the button to the right (the one with this line of code) turns into a red square button rather than to a red button with soft edges.